# nginx - specify different index file name for subdirectory

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want the directory index file in the root of my site to be `index.html` but within a subdirectory `/foo` I want it to be `bar.html`

i.e.

- /index.html
- /foo/bar.html

Also I want requests to `/foo` or `/foo/` or `/foo/:anything` to resolve to `bar.html`

- Why doesn't my location block /foo work?
- How do I specify the location block for /foo ?

Here's the server definition:

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name  domain.tld;
  port_in_redirect off;

  location / {
    # ssl is terminated at our load bal
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
      rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    root   /usr/share/nginx/mysite/public;
    index  index.html;
    add_header Cache-Control "public max-age=600";
    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    charset UTF-8;
  }

  # this location doesn't work  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  location /foo {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/mysite/public/foo;
    index  bar.html;
  }

  # set expiration of assets to 30d for caching
  location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/mysite/public;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

EDIT: I also had the following at the bottom of that server block.

```
error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /404.html {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/www;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/www;
}
```

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have `bar.html` as index file use:

```
location /foo {
    index bar.html;
}
```

If you wish any request to `/foo/anything` end up in `/foo/bar.html` use this:

```
location = /foo {
    try_files /foo/bar.html =404;
}

location /foo/ {
    try_files /foo/bar.html =404;
}
```

In your `location` you have the wrong `root` directive.

In your config nginx end up looking for the file `/usr/share/nginx/mysite/public/foo/foo/bar.html`

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work eventually... I actually omitted two error page definitions (now added to the question). Your answer didn't work until I removed those. What's going on there?

Comment: WHat doesn't work?

Comment: I _was_ getting a 404 error at `/foo` if I **only** added `location / foo { index bar.html; }`. The error page locations were (I think) a red herring - I had to add the `root` definition back into your `/foo` block and now it's giving me `bar.html` as intended.

Comment: To simplify: the `root` path needs to be defined in every `location` block otherwise a 404 error is returned for that location.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you defined `root` inside `location /`. Just define it on server level once. See also http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block.